# mobile credit card swiping systems with API

Tags: android, ios, api, credit-card

I'm looking for a credit card swiping system for ios/androids that comes with an API. PayPal Here and Square are two well known companies that offers the card swiping, but they do not yet have an API.

Payanywhere is another service with an API, but unfortunately it's API is limited and doesn't have what I need.

Is there another service that has something like this?

just to clarify, I am writing an app that uses the swiping system that I will be distributing to my users. Thus, I cannot have the client side dictate how much is paid, otherwise the client side could be hacked and the client could just pay however they want.

Additionally, I need the payanywhere server to tell my server the status of a transaction. Same reason, otherwise the client can send fake statuses and fool my server.

Comment: What do you need from the API? How is payanywhere limited?

Comment: @mkral I need the API to support communication between the payanywhere server and my own server.

Comment: i would appreciate a reason for the close vote

Comment: I really don't know if it's possible but I would imagine when the paypal here is available it will use their paypal sdk which has iOS support.

Comment: How about you use payanywhere and on confirmation of transaction you send the details to your server for validation. It also looks like you can specify the amount. Will clients have access to your code?

Comment: @mkral well, clients can always reverse engineer my app, so thats why I want to make sure that they dont have the ability to do anything. The problem is that having the client send anything that they can directly modify would be insecure. Paypal has a nice way of handling this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post comments yet due to low rep being a new user here, so throwing this in as an answer.

Are you wanting to have a peripheral device with api to use for card reading, but then do your own server/transaction approval process instead of being tied to one card processesing gateway?

If so, yes, there are hardware manufacturer's that aren't tied to a specific gateway that charges x% of every transaction.  instead they offer a api (iOS library) that interacts with their peripheral/sled. It's then up to your objective C code to handle the transaction/card info and interact with whatever gateway you choose.

I think magtek idynamo is one. Look for the hardware manufacturer and you'll find a few that offer iOS libraries with their device.